# How to set specific labels to seaborn graph?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, seaborn

I have a data frame:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

val = random.sample(range(0, 1000), 1000)
prob = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    prob.append(x)   
d = {'Value': val, 'Probability': prob}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Here, I create an additional dataframe  based on the values of df:

```
group_prob = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Probability'], np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)))['Value'].mean()
group_prob = group_prob.fillna(0.0)
group_prob = pd.DataFrame(group_prob)
group_prob["Count"] = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Probability'], np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)))['Value'].count()
group_prob["Text"] = group_prob['Value'].round(2).astype(str)+' - '+group_prob['Count'].astype(str)
```

I want to create a bar plot:

```
def barplot_groups(group_, var_names=['','']):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
    sns.barplot(group_.index, group_.values, ax=ax)
    max_val = group_.values.max()
    plt.xlabel(f'{var_names[0]}')
    plt.ylabel(f'Average of {var_names[1]}')
    plt.title(f'Relationship between {var_names[0]} and {var_names[1]}')
    plt.show()
```

This is my results:

```
barplot_groups(group_prob['Value'], ['Probability','Value'])
```

I also want to add labels to the plot based on `group_prob['Text']`, since the values are long I want to place them vertically, what is the best way to do it using seaborn library?
This is an example what I am trying to add (the white boarder is not needed).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With matplotlib 3.4.0 or newer, [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html?highlight=bar_label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label) can be applied from a collection of labels like `group_prob['Text']`:

```
def barplot_groups(group_, my_labels, var_names):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
    sns.barplot(x=group_.index, y=group_.values, ax=ax)
    ax.set(xlabel=f'{var_names[0]}',
           ylabel=f'Average of {var_names[1]}',
           title=f'Relationship between {var_names[0]} and {var_names[1]}')

    ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=my_labels, label_type='center',
                 rotation=90)
    plt.show()
```

Function call:

```
barplot_groups(group_prob['Value'],
               my_labels=group_prob['Text'],
               var_names=['Probability', 'Value'])
```

`group_prob`:

```
                  Value  Count          Text
Probability                                 
(0.0, 0.1]   482.278846    104  482.28 - 104
(0.1, 0.2]   495.018692    107  495.02 - 107
(0.2, 0.3]   529.750000     92   529.75 - 92
(0.3, 0.4]   490.933333    105  490.93 - 105
(0.4, 0.5]   469.858491    106  469.86 - 106
(0.5, 0.6]   515.640777    103  515.64 - 103
(0.6, 0.7]   545.450980    102  545.45 - 102
(0.7, 0.8]   458.900000     80    458.9 - 80
(0.8, 0.9]   468.100000    110   468.1 - 110
(0.9, 1.0]   542.153846     91   542.15 - 91
```

[image: plot]

---

Just add `backgroundcolor='white'` to `bar_label` for a white background:

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=my_labels, label_type='center',
             rotation=90, backgroundcolor='white')
```

[image: plot 2]

---

Reproduceable with seed 5:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

random.seed(5)
val = random.sample(range(0, 1000), 1000)
prob = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    prob.append(x)
d = {'Value': val, 'Probability': prob}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

group_prob = df.groupby(
    pd.cut(df['Probability'], np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
)['Value'].mean()
group_prob = group_prob.fillna(0.0)
group_prob = pd.DataFrame(group_prob)
group_prob["Count"] = df.groupby(
    pd.cut(df['Probability'], np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
)['Value'].count()
group_prob["Text"] = (
        group_prob['Value'].round(2).astype(str)
        + ' - ' +
        group_prob['Count'].astype(str)
)
```

Comment: This solution is looking great, currently I am trying to update my conda using - conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib==3.4.0 , but I got an error "The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - matplotlib==3.4.0"

Comment: I don't use `conda` much but isn't version specific installations for condas a single equal sign? `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.4.2`

Comment: Looks like it is available for Python 3.7 - I have 3.6 - I will try to update

Comment: Thank You very much! I updated the version of Python and installed the updated matplotlib!This is exactly what I wanted to do!